# SOAP request with 500 error

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I'm using the NuSOAP and i'm trying to make a request but always getting the 500 error:

```
<?php
require_once('../lib/nusoap.php');

$c = new soapclient('http://example.com/index.asmx?WSDL');

$clientVAT = $c->call('GetClient',
              array(
                'empresa' => '*****',
                'password' => '******',
                'nif' => '*******',
                ));

echo "clientVAT $clientVAT.";

?>
```

Shouldn't this be enough to get a response from the server?

Comment: Do you have more details about the error? have you tried it in SoapUI ?

Comment: Anas, i gave up using nusoap, i'm using the native soapcall from php 5+ . But i must thank you and i would up vote you if i had the chance but no can do for now. Will wait for the 15 reputation needed and come back later.

Comment: Turn on debug and get the last request and response. http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php

Comment: Glad I could help, Yes the native php 5 Soap is way better, you can also check the zend framework version if you need advanced features, SoapUI is your friend to debug - You can accept the answer thow

Comment: @MikeB Sorry but it's not a blind suggestions, I dealed with the same issues many times, and when I checked his WSDL, there are 2 levels before the parameters, that's why you need to send a 2 levels array !!

Comment: @MikeB Well I needed to know if it will work first !! Plus you could have just suggested that I should add more details to my answer instead of calling it 'Blind suggestions'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your wsdl, you have a complexType with 2 levels

```
<s:element name="GetClientesNif">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="empresa" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="nif" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

That's why you need to send a request with a 2 levels array :

Try with this :

```
$myArray[] = array(
                'empresa' => '*****',
                'password' => '******',
                'nif' => '*******',
                );

$clientVAT = $c->call('GetClientesNif', $myArray);
```